# VBA for hiding rows based on value

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a VBA code to select any row where a special value appears in a chosen column.

```
`Sub test()
vonZeile = 4    ' first row
bisZeile = Cells(vonZeile, 7).End(xlDown).Row
Spalte = 7   ' column G
Markierung = False
For Zeile = bisZeile To vonZeile Step -1
  If (Cells(Zeile, Spalte).Value = "Werkstatt") Then
    If Markierung Then
      Union(Selection, Rows(Zeile)).Select
    Else
      Rows(Zeile).Select
      Markierung = True
    End If
  End If
Next Zeile
If Zeilen > "" Then Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub`
```

This might not be the prettiest but it works pretty well and very fast.

Now I would like to change this code so that the rows with the specific value are not only selected but cut out or hidden. 
I couldn't figure out how to change this code to get this.

I have a different code that does delete all these rows but it lats an eternity. But it should be much faster when all the rows with the specific value would be deleted at once.

Shouldn't there be a way to just change the `.Select` part in the code to maybe `Hidden` or `Delete`? 
This is just a guessing as I am not very familiar with VBA coding.

Very happy to get some advice on this matter. 
Thanks

Comment: You could do `Rows(Zeile).Hidden = true` to hide them. You may find your delete version of this to be faster if you toggle off the `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False` before running it (then toggle it back on after the deletions.

Comment: Thanks that actually works perfect and very fast...but the problem is that it now hides everything BUT the rows with the value "Werkstatt". I tried to Switch the If and Else conditions and also changed the value "Werkstatt" to the other value that has to be shown but no difference. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fastest way I've found to do this: create an array the size of your original data, loop through the rows adding the keepers to the array, then clear all of the data from the worksheet(far less time consuming than deleting) and then lastly write the array of stored data to the sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim firstRow As Integer, lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer, criteriaCol As Integer
    Dim criteriaValue As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim iRow As Integer, iCol As Integer, iCounter As Integer

    'Set this to the worksheet you want to perform this procedure on
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    'Set your first row, last row, criteria column, and last column
    firstRow = 4
    lastRow = Cells(firstRow, 7).End(xlDown).Row
    lastCol = 7
    criteriaCol = 7
    criteriaValue = "Werkstatt"

    'Resize the array to fit the length of your sheet
    ReDim arr(1 To (lastRow - firstRow), 1 To lastCol)

    'iCounter is used to track the position of the first dimension in arr
    iCounter = 1

    'For each row, if the value you are looking for matches then loop through each column and write it to the array
    For iRow = firstRow To lastRow
        If ws.Cells(iRow, criteriaCol).Value = criteriaValue Then
            For iCol = 1 To lastCol
                arr(iCounter, iCol) = ws.Cells(iRow, iCol)
            Next
            iCounter = iCounter + 1
        End If
    Next iRow

    'Clear the specific rows on the sheet
    ws.Rows(firstRow & ":" & lastRow).Cells.Clear

    'Resize the range to fit the array and write it the worksheet
    ws.Cells(firstRow, 1).Resize(firstRow + iCounter - 1, lastCol) = arr

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks...but I get some Errors and have to Change the Else condition to `arr(iArr) = Rows(iRow)` and also the 4th line to `lastRow = Cells(firstRow, 7).End(xlDown).Row`. But then the result is that the whole sheet is cleared completely.

Comment: Okay, I've updated the code and added in a few other variables which you can customize.  I've tested this out so everything should work this time.

Comment: Thanks @pheeper. I tried some customizations but still this unfortunately does not work for me as I'd like to. First, all the other cells in the other columns are deleted as well. So the rows do not stay complete. But the second and bigger problem is that some rows with the chosen value (here "Werkstatt") are also being deleted. In my example only 31 out of 40 were chosen.

Comment: @os23 in your OP you stated you wanted the rows to be cut or deleted so that's what this does.  If your row goes past column G then you need to update the "lastCol = 7" line.  In regards to the rows with "Werkstatt" being deleted, check and see if they have a trailing space or two (use the `=len()` formula on the worksheet).  If that's the case let me know and I can update my answer to correct that.

Comment: I adjusted `lastCol` and now more values appear but they're not kept but changed. This should not happen.
Maybe I misexplained. What I'm looking for is the following: 
Let there be a e.g. 5x5 Matrix, all cells filled. In the first column A there are three types of values e.g. a,b,a,b,c. My Goal is to delete all the rows where in column A the value b appears. The rows with the values a and c in column A should not be touched at all (from A to E).
My own code does select all these rows and with the "del" button I can delete them. This I want to be done automatically.
Thank you

Comment: Have you tried changing `criteriaCol = 7` to 1 (for col A) and `criteriaValue = "Werkstatt"` to "b" for the value?  If you set the values properly this will work.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I did. In my `criteriaCol` there is only my `criteriaValue` "Werkstatt" left as I wished. But in all the other cells all the numbers are totally mixed up. Like a lot of rows are just filled to the bottom with the value of the first cell in this row. But not all the rows behave like this. So there is no logic.  Then again other rows are fully cleared or contain numbers that have nothing to do with the ones in the original cells before executing the code.

Answer (score 0):

I now found the answer to my problem. It is just a change of one single line. I deleted the last line in my code `If Zeilen > "" Then Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp` and replaced it by the following line `Selection.EntireRow.Delete`. This solves the problem and it also works fast which was very important to me. Thanks everyone for the help!